# How to implement a popup menu in Swing that works both under Windows and Linux

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, popupmenu

I have been wondering multiple times over the past why some of my Java/Swing **popup menus** seem to work under *Linux* but not under *Windows* and vice versa. So how do I implement a popup menu that works on both OS'es?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for working examples.

It shows how to use the `isPopupTrigger()` method of the `MouseEvent`.

Or you can use the `setComponentPopupMenu(...)` method of `JComponent` which has been around since JDK 1.5 and you don't have to worry about the MouseListener.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, a call to MouseEvent::isPopupTrigger will work fine in the mouseReleased method, but returns always false when called from within the mousePressed method. In Linux, the opposite is the case.

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    checkPopup(e); // triggers the popup event under Linux but not under Windows
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    checkPopup(e); // triggers the popup event under Windows but not under Linux
}

private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.isPopupTrigger())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: As the link provided by @camickr mentions, it is not so much the OS that matters, but the LAF you are using.